# Storing my game score in local storage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm pretty new to JS so I'm struggling here. Basically I have a score function in place in my JavaScript and I want to store this locally so it can be retrieved by another page at a later time. I used local storage for my login and register page, but I'm not sure how I can do the same for score.

```
add_row_of_pipes: function() {
    var hole = Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1;

    for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        if (i != hole && i != hole +1) 
            this.add_one_pipe(400, i*60+10);   

    this.score += 1;
    this.label_score.content = this.score;
};
```

All feedback will be highly appreciated:)

Comment: `localStorage.setItem('score', this.score);`? I'm really unsure what your issue is.

Comment: How did you store data for the login page and how is it different from storing any other thing, like your score?

Comment: If you are able to use `localStorage` in one page then why not able to use that in another page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can store and retrieve values from localStorage:

// Store

`localStorage.setItem("score", "100");`

// Retrieve

`var score = localStorage.getItem("score");`

Answer (score 0):

This is a small LocalStorage framework that i've put together.
It covers all of the obvious functionality you would want from localstorage.

```
 function set_LocalStorage(key,value)
{
 //localStorage.setItem("name of variable", "value to store");
   localStorage.setItem(key, value);
   console.log('LocalStorage: ' + key + ' has been set to: ' + value);
}//End set_LocalStorage


function get_LocalStorage(key)
{
  return localStorage.getItem(key);
  console.log('LocalStorage: ' + key + ' has a value of: ' + value);
}//End get_LocalStorage


function remove_LocalStorage(key)
{
  localStorage.removeItem(key);
  console.log('LocalStorage: ' + key + ' has been removed');
}//End remove_LocalStorage


function check_LocalStorage_exist(key)
{
  var v = get_LocalStorage(key); 
  var v2 = toInteger(v);
  var FeedBack;

  if(v2 == 'null' || v2 === 'NaN' || v2 == 'undefined' || v2 == ''){ /*console.log('key '+key+' does NOT exist');*/ FeedBack='NO';}
  if(v2!=0){ 
      console.log('key '+key+' exist');
        FeedBack='YES';
    }

  return FeedBack;
}//End check_LocalStorage




function list_All_LocalStorage()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
   {
    let item = localStorage.getItem(localStorage.key(i));   //--Will only need to have this on when collecting APP_DATA
    console.log('------ LocalStorage: '+localStorage.key(i)+' = '+item); 
   }

}//End list_All_LocalStorage



function remove_All_LocalStorage()
{
  for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++)
   {
    let s_key = localStorage.key(i);
    remove_LocalStorage(s_key);
   }

}//End remove_All_LocalStorage
```

You're welcome! :)